# Refactoring: Extracting interface

Tags: c#-3.0, refactoring, extract

I am refactoring my existing code. I've extracted interfaces from my existing classes. I have created a separate class library which holds all such interfaces. 
My problem is I have some classes with structures and enums. These classes also have some methods returning these structures and enums.

I want to extract interface from these class. But I am now worried about the structures and enums. I can't have these structures and enums extracted in my interface and hence methods returning structure and enums do not reflect easily in extraction.

How can I overcome this situation wherein I want to have structure and enums in my extracted interface? Do I need to break the structure and have to use it as members of interface? How can I define methods returning structure in interface?

Comment: If the structures and enums are defined outside of the interface, there shouldn't be a problem, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, structures and enums are outside the interface but they are part of classes for which I want to extract interfaces. I want to keep these extracted interfaces in separate class library. This library does not refer the library containing classes, rather the library of extracted & compiled interfaces is referred by existing class library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structures and enums generally shouldn't be nested- unlike classes, they are often part of the 'public contract' of the type, and so you'd typically extract them into their own files and put them in the shared class library with the interfaces.